# How can I theme the Captcha/ReCaptcha error message?

Tags: 8, captcha

I'd like to change how the error message is when a user fails the recpatcha.

Currently it is just plain text on top of my form but I would rather have it be a modal or at least be in red.

I looked into the templates folder in both the Captcha module and ReCaptcha but did not see anything for the error message.

Is there a way to theme the error message?

Answer (score 2):

Believe I found a solution.

Since I am using the captcha with Webforms I inserted the below JS to the form and it seems to be working without any drawbacks.

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
Drupal.behaviors.myModuleBehavior = {
attach: function (context, settings) {
$( "[role=alert]" ).dialog();
}
};
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```